# Highcharts stock chart based on data from Quandl API

Tags: json, highcharts

I would like to use the "Highstock" charting tool from HighCharts.com to create a stock chart based on price data from Quandl's API.

By using Quandl's API, I can get price information on a stock for each trading day. For instance, the following URL would give me Microsoft's stock price each day since January 3rd 2015 to February 3rd 2015 in a Json format.

[Quandl.com Json link](https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/YAHOO/MSFT.json?start_date=2015-01-03&end_date=2015-02-03&order=asc)

The problem is that this Json format does not correspond to the format that Highstock expects. The format that Highstock expects looks like this:

[Highcharts Json link](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?)

So the question is can I convert the Json output from Quandl to correspond to the Json format that Highstock expects? Or can I modify the Highstock code to accept the Quandl Json format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty easy conversion in JavaScript:

```
  var hiJson = quandlJson.dataset.data.map(function(d){
    return [new Date(d[0]).getTime(), d[4]];
  });
```

This would return an array of arrays of `date in milliseconds` and `close price`.

---

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="highstock@0.0.1" data-semver="0.0.1" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script data-require="highstock@0.0.1" data-semver="0.0.1" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    var json = {
      "dataset": {
        "id": 9775138,
        "dataset_code": "MSFT",
        "database_code": "YAHOO",
        "name": "MSFT: Microsoft Corporation -",
        "description": "Exchange : . Key Statistics",
        "refreshed_at": "2015-10-18T19:49:01.957Z",
        "newest_available_date": "2015-10-16",
        "oldest_available_date": "1986-03-13",
        "column_names": ["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted Close"],
        "frequency": "daily",
        "type": "Time Series",
        "premium": false,
        "limit": null,
        "transform": null,
        "column_index": null,
        "start_date": "2015-01-03",
        "end_date": "2015-02-03",
        "data": [
          ["2015-01-05", 46.369999, 46.73, 46.25, 46.330002, 39673900.0, 45.406156],
          ["2015-01-06", 46.380001, 46.75, 45.540001, 45.650002, 36447900.0, 44.739715],
          ["2015-01-07", 45.98, 46.459999, 45.490002, 46.23, 29114100.0, 45.308148],
          ["2015-01-08", 46.75, 47.75, 46.720001, 47.59, 29645200.0, 46.641029],
          ["2015-01-09", 47.610001, 47.82, 46.900002, 47.189999, 23942800.0, 46.249004],
          ["2015-01-12", 47.419998, 47.540001, 46.360001, 46.599998, 23651900.0, 45.670769],
          ["2015-01-13", 46.970001, 47.91, 46.060001, 46.360001, 35270600.0, 45.435556],
          ["2015-01-14", 45.959999, 46.240002, 45.619999, 45.959999, 29719600.0, 45.043531],
          ["2015-01-15", 46.220001, 46.380001, 45.41, 45.48, 32742300.0, 44.573103],
          ["2015-01-16", 45.310001, 46.279999, 45.169998, 46.240002, 35695300.0, 45.31795],
          ["2015-01-20", 46.299999, 46.650002, 45.57, 46.389999, 36161900.0, 45.464957],
          ["2015-01-21", 45.939999, 46.139999, 45.48, 45.919998, 39081100.0, 45.004328],
          ["2015-01-22", 46.380001, 47.139999, 46.080002, 47.130001, 35898000.0, 46.190203],
          ["2015-01-23", 47.360001, 47.389999, 46.799999, 47.18, 26211600.0, 46.239205],
          ["2015-01-26", 47.0, 47.130001, 46.240002, 47.009998, 42525500.0, 46.072593],
          ["2015-01-27", 42.950001, 43.200001, 42.110001, 42.66, 169164000.0, 41.809336],
          ["2015-01-28", 42.740002, 42.790001, 41.16, 41.189999, 84507100.0, 40.368647],
          ["2015-01-29", 40.93, 42.119999, 40.790001, 42.009998, 63585300.0, 41.172296],
          ["2015-01-30", 41.549999, 41.580002, 40.349998, 40.400002, 78004900.0, 39.594403],
          ["2015-02-02", 40.59, 41.369999, 40.23, 41.279999, 50352500.0, 40.456853],
          ["2015-02-03", 41.630001, 41.93, 41.049999, 41.599998, 52082400.0, 40.770471]
        ],
        "collapse": null,
        "order": "asc",
        "database_id": 394
      }
    };

    var hiJson = json.dataset.data.map(function(d) {
      return [new Date(d[0]).getTime(), d[4]]
    });

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },
      title: {
        text: 'MS Stock Price'
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'MS',
        data: hiJson,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Full example with AJAX:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="highstock@0.0.1" data-semver="0.0.1" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script data-require="highstock@0.0.1" data-semver="0.0.1" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    $.getJSON('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/YAHOO/MSFT.json?start_date=2015-01-03&end_date=2015-02-03&order=asc', function(json) {
        var hiJson = json.dataset.data.map(function(d) {
          return [new Date(d[0]).getTime(), d[4]]
        });

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
          rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
          },
          title: {
            text: 'MS Stock Price'
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'MS',
            data: hiJson,
            tooltip: {
              valueDecimals: 2
            }
          }]
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see :-) My Javascript is a bit rusty, so the question is how can your example be modified, so that the stock price data in the Javascript is NOT hardcoded, but comes dynamically from [link]https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/YAHOO/MSFT.json?start_date=2015-01-03&end_date=2015-02-03&order=asc

Comment: @ThomasJackson, you issue an ajax request.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work the way I wanted because the data wouldn't load before the chart was being created. Unfortunately I had to get the data loaded in Json then call the chart creation function. Was disappointed with that, but at least it worked based on what you guys have here.

Answer (score 0):

The `.getTime()` method doesn't work on a string. Instead you should use `Date.parse()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="highstock@0.0.1" data-semver="0.0.1" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script data-require="highstock@0.0.1" data-semver="0.0.1" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    $.getJSON('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/YAHOO/MSFT.json?start_date=2015-01-03&end_date=2015-02-03&order=asc', function(json) {
        var hiJson = json.dataset.data.map(function(d) {
          return [Date.parse(d[0]), d[4]]
        });

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
          rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
          },
          title: {
            text: 'MS Stock Price'
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'MS',
            data: hiJson,
            tooltip: {
              valueDecimals: 2
            }
          }]
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```